# Eclipse error: No file system is defined for scheme: C

Tags: eclipse, microchip

I'm using SoftConsole 2022.2 which is based on Eclipse 4.22.0.v20211124-1800.

When I attempt to issue a headless build from the command prompt for a C project I get the highlighted error below in the .log file. This only happens with the Windows version of SoftConsole(eclipse). It runs perfectly under linux using the same version.

Does anyone understand what in the world it's complaining about and how I can fix it? The best I can guess is it's something to do with a C project file layout?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2023-11-29 16:37:06.813
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
# org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No file system is defined for scheme: C
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.InternalFileSystemCore.getFileSystem(InternalFileSystemCore.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.InternalFileSystemCore.getStore(InternalFileSystemCore.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.EFS.getStore(EFS.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.HeadlessBuilder.importProject(HeadlessBuilder.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.HeadlessBuilder.start(HeadlessBuilder.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.headlessbuilderapp.HeadlessBuilderWrapper.start(HeadlessBuilderWrapper.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

I found some obscure references to a similar error about meminfo or something instead of C that may be fixed by installing WikiText. I tried this and it does nothing.

Comment: Maybe `No file system is defined for scheme: C` is caused by a path starting with `C:\...` rather than with `file:///C:/...` that is mistakenly interpreted as an [URI where the first part before `:` is the scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).

Comment: You are correct. It appears to be gagging on the -import [uri:/]/path/to/project argument. I'm attempting to run this under mingw64 on windows so I'm using linux paths on a windows machine. Yes, this is probably stupid, but I already have scripts that run on linux great and it would be awesome to be able to reuse them. If I change the path /c/path/to/project to /e/path/to/project the error becomes no scheme: E. This doesn't seem to be a problem with the -data switch.

Comment: I got it. For some reason, you have to use an escaped windows path on the -import switch. You do not have to do this on the -data switch.

Comment: Great. Please consider to give a self-answer to help others. Please also make sure this has been reported to the SoftConsole project.